# There was an error generating the XML document in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json, xml

I am trying out with this code but it give me error and I want to use only data table not data set

```
 [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public DataTable NameArray()
        {
            DataTable imageTable = new DataTable("gcm");
            // imageTable.Columns.Add("image_name", typeof(String));
            imageTable.Columns.Add("username", typeof(String));
            imageTable.Columns.Add("gcmkey", typeof(String));
            if (con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            string query = "SELECT * from gcm";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    imageTable.Rows.Add(reader["username"],reader["gcmkey"]);
                }
            }
          this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            this.Context.Response.Write(json.Serialize(new { PersonalProfile = reader }));
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
            return imageTable; }
```

Error show me like:

```
 This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

So, how can I get data from datatable, not in data set?

Comment: Why don't use use SQlDataAdapter to fill data table instead of SqlDataReader?  The fill into datatable is one instruction.  The code looks like it should work.  So either the reader code has an error or there is no rows being returned from the query.  These arre the only two reasons why you would get an error message that the document is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the exception?

> Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set.

Give a name to your table:

```
DataTable imageTable = new DataTable("tableName");
```

Comment: Now it show me `error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty`

Comment: Well, That should be another question, but i guess it's because the Response.Write you are doing. why is that? You return the DataTable, there is not reason to serialize the reader too

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to the data table
The error state that you should set a name to the data table.pls do so.
e.g

```
dt.TableName = "myTable";
dt.WriteXml(@"path", true);
```